# Display data using FILTER formula not working

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArRTKzjFb6WsdGdiU3hCRFRhOGxzUkhLYUJIcEMwSlE%60) Google Sheets.

In sheet named `Archive` I have imported some tweets. In Sheet1 I have the following formula:

```
=FILTER('Archive'!A2:A;MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&A2:A&" ");" "&'Archive'!A2:A&" ");SIGN(ROW('Archive'!A2:A))))
```

What I would like to do is to display specific tweets from sheet Archive, containing specific keywords listed on Sheet1. This formula should work, but not in this case when I am importing data. All I get is a `#N/A`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed on the sheet chat window, use:

`=FILTER('Archive'!A2:A;MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&A2:A&" ");" "&TRIM('Archive'!A2:A)&" ");SIGN(ROW(A2:A))))`

In short, the second argument of MMULT needs to have as many rows as there are columns in the first argument. Here is a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiZdNQHjqWKqdHowMlZQcUpsSEFFZVh3Wm8xdHhkV3c&authkey=CKC8i9AP&authkey=CKC8i9AP#gid=2) that tries to describe MMULT used in this sort of way.

The TRIM part is to mitigate against spurious space characters that may be in the raw data.

Comment: Once again AdamL did it. Thank you!